# Creating a TXT file with e-mail address from a .msg file

Tags: python, email, txt

First of all, I'm learning, so for many this question should be simple, and would be very grateful for any kind of help.

I have a dir with many .msg files, which I need to open, take the e-mail address on the body and put on a txt file, containing a e-mail address for each .msg file.

Unfortunately, my code breaks on this step, where the error code show:

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9c' in position 742: character maps to "

```
path = r'C:\Dev\Canedo\a.msg'
mail = open(path, encoding='Latin-1')
mail_contents = mail.read()
t = open("relat.txt", "w+")
t.write(mail_contents)
```

I also tried this, but without success:

```
path = r'C:\Dev\Canedo\a.msg'
mail = open(path, encoding='Latin-1')
mail_contents = mail.read()
t = open("relat.txt", "w+")
t.write(mail_contents, encoding='Latin-1')
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where did the .msg files come from? What format are they in? What makes you think that `encoding='Latin-1` is appropriate?

Comment: If these are Microsoft msg files you'll need to be aware that they are not text-based (i.e., binary) so You'll need to know how they're structured internally. You will also need to bear in mind that a msg doesn't necessarily represent an email. It could, for example, be a calendar entry

Comment: @RogerLipscombe the .msg files come from Outlook. The encoding seems inappropriate when i print, but the utf-8 dont even print.

Comment: @OldBill Actually, this msg files comes from Outlook, and are not-delivered e-mail alerts, wich i need to collect this not-send adress, and put all in a txt file. I know im being dumb, but i really want to learn this.

Comment: @JameBernabe You will need to refer to Microsoft's documentation in order to understand how to access the internals of a msg file. There may even be a Python module for this somewhere

Comment: @JameBernabe Yes there is, Use  `extract-msg` https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor